# Why is there no inversion type?

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence, I'm confused with the use of 'not for nothing'. No inversion follows 'not for nothing'.

> Not for nothing one face, one character, one fact makes much more impression on him, and another none. (Ralph Waldo Emerson)

Comment: Emerson is writing poetry, not prose.  With poetry you may write whatever you want, ignoring any grammar rules you wish.

Comment: I think Andrew overstates things :)

Answer (score 1):

Emerson is writing about individuality.

**Not for nothing** = some reason or purpose is involved

We can paraphrase his sentence using a more contemporary syntax, as follows:

> It is not for nothing that one face, one character, one fact makes
>   much more impression on him, and on another, no impression at all.

or if we use inversion:

> Not for nothing does one face, one character, one fact make much more impression on him and on another, no impression at all.

That is, it is not a matter of mere happenstance or complete randomness that on one person a great impression is made by a face, or a character, or a fact, and on another person the same face, character, or fact will make no impression whatsoever.

Perhaps Emerson should have written **a great impression** instead of **much more impression**.